# How to write the output of data in tensorflow

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow

I have been following this tutorial to understand linear classification model and its applications. I have taken a different example outside the census data and I can get the accuracy with `evaluate`.

Now what I am interested is to **print out rows of test data** with the predicted column values.

https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/wide

```
import random
import pandas
import tensorflow as tf
import tempfile
import numpy as np

df_train = pandas.read_csv('input/train.csv', usecols=['Sex', 'Age', 'Fare','Survived', 'SibSp'])
df_test = pandas.read_csv('input/test.csv', usecols=['Sex', 'Age', 'Fare', 'SibSp'])
df_test['Survived'] = 0
CATEGORICAL_COLUMNS = ['Sex']
CONTINUOUS_COLUMNS = ['Age', 'Fare', 'SibSp']
df_train_nona = df_train.dropna()
df_test_nona = df_test.dropna()
print(df_test_nona)
def input_fn(df):
    continuous_cols = {k: tf.constant(df[k].values)
                       for k in CONTINUOUS_COLUMNS}

    categorical_cols = {k: tf.SparseTensor(
        indices=[[i,0] for i in range(df[k].size)],
        values=df[k].values,
        dense_shape=[df[k].size, 1])
        for k in CATEGORICAL_COLUMNS
    }

    feature_cols = dict(list(continuous_cols.items()) + list(categorical_cols.items()))

    label = tf.constant(df['Survived'].values)

    return feature_cols, label

def train_input_fn():
    return input_fn(df_train_nona)

def eval_input_fn():
    return input_fn(df_test_nona)

gender = tf.contrib.layers.sparse_column_with_keys(
    column_name='Sex', keys=['female', 'male']
)

pclass = tf.contrib.layers.real_valued_column('Pclass')

cabin = tf.contrib.layers.sparse_column_with_hash_bucket("Cabin", hash_bucket_size=1000)

age = tf.contrib.layers.real_valued_column('Age')
fare = tf.contrib.layers.real_valued_column('Fare')
parch = tf.contrib.layers.real_valued_column('Parch')
sibsp = tf.contrib.layers.real_valued_column('SibSp')

model_dir = tempfile.mkdtemp()

m = tf.contrib.learn.LinearClassifier(feature_columns=[gender, age, fare, sibsp], optimizer=tf.train.FtrlOptimizer(
      learning_rate=0.1,
      l1_regularization_strength=0.001
    ),model_dir=model_dir)

m.fit(input_fn = train_input_fn, steps=400)
```

Comment: Is this using an Estimator? They do have a `predict()` method, which sounds like what you want.

Comment: @AllenLavoie I am able to use the `predict()` method to get the column I am predicting. I only receive the one column with I iterate through the generator. Does it preserve the order of the test rows I pass to estimator? I added my sample code (dont laugh at the silliness :) I am very new to tensor flow and ML)

Comment: Yes, `predict()` will just iterate over the batch dimension of the output. It doesn't look like there's any shuffling in your input function, so the order should be the same as the input.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to just take the input data and run in through the network function. I believe this should be `sess.run(output_tensor, feed_dict={x: input_data})`.

Comment: does the `input_data` correspond to an input function like mine in the description?

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you create two floating points

```
node1 = tf.constant(3.0, dtype=tf.float32)
node2 = tf.constant(4.0) # also tf.float32 implicitly
print(node1, node2)
```

Above code will print this

```
Tensor("Const:0", shape=(), dtype=float32) Tensor("Const_1:0", shape=(), dtype=float32)
```

But you probably don't want it to be printed like that. Try using `sess = tf.Session()`

```
sess = tf.Session()
print(sess.run([node1, node2]))
```

It will be printed like this

```
[3.0, 4.0]
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: would this work with my example above? Not sure how to use this approach with the crappy code I have :)

Comment: would this work with my example above? Not sure how to use this approach with the crappy code I have :)